# What should be a generic enough convergence criteria of Stochastic Gradient Descent

Tags: machine-learning

I am implementing a generic module for Stochastic Gradient Descent. That takes arguments: training dataset, loss(x,y), dw(x,y) - per sample loss and per sample gradient change.

Now, for the convergence criteria, I have thought of :-

a) Checking loss function after every 10% of the dataset.size, averaged over some window

b) Checking the norm of the differences between weight vector, after every 10-20% of dataset size

c) Stabilization of error on the training set.

d) Change in the sign of the gradient (again, checked after every fixed intervals) -

I have noticed that these checks (precision of check etc.) depends on other stuff also, like step size, learning rate.. and the effect can vary from one training problem to another.

I can't seem to make up mind on, what should be the generic stopping criterion, regardless of the training set, fx,df/dw thrown at the SGD module. What do you guys do?

Also, for (d), what would be the meaning of "change in sign" for a n-dimensional vector? As, in - given dw_i, dw_i+1, how do I detect the change of sign, does it even have a meaning in more than 2 dimensions?

P.S. Apologies for non-math/latex symbols..still getting used to the stuff.

Answer (score 3):

First, stochastic gradient descent is the on-line version of gradient descent method. The update rule is using a single example at a time.

Suppose, `f(x)` is your cost function for a single example, the stopping criteria of SGD for N-dimensional vector is usually:

[image]

[image]

See this<sup>[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSp7t.png)</sup>, or this<sup>[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GaAhH.png)</sup> for details.

Second, there is a further twist on stochastic gradient descent using so-called “minibatches”. It works identically to SGD, except that it uses more than one training example to make each estimate of the gradient. This technique reduces variance in the estimate of the gradient, and often makes better use of the hierarchical memory organization in modern computers. See this<sup>[3](http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/gettingstarted.html#stochastic-gradient-descent)</sup>.

Comment: Thanks. I understood all the concepts you have mentioned - was just wondering, what do people use in actual generic implementation of SGD.

Also, someone suggested to check the change in weight vector between epochs. Which, as per my understanding, may not be a good advantage over the normal batch version.

Comment: BTw, do you check this "delta f(x)" between running samples? It may be quite unstable, due to stochastic movement of the gradient (df/dw) vector!!